# Emails can't send in laravel 5 project

Tags: laravel-5

No any errors return. But can't send emails.

```
 public function contact(){
    Mail::send('emails.password',['j'=>'grt'],function($message){
        $message->to('abc@gmail.com','efe')->from('def@gmail.com')->subject('esf');
    })
    return view('contact');
}
```

Suppose above two emails are existing. And I have used the use Mail alias also.

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER','smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST','smtp.mailgun.org') ,
'port' => 587,
'from' => ['address' => 'kidscorner2016sep@gmail.com', 'name' => 'kidscorner'],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' =>env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Above is the mail.php

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Looks good. Maybe the problem is not laravel but sendmail. Review laravel's logs and sendmail's logs too.

Comment: How can they change?